# Existence of unique maximizer in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

This sounds like a very basic question, but I have a hard time pinpointing the necessary and sufficient conditions...

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. I want to prove that there is a *unique* maximizer $\pmb{x}^\star \in \mathbb{R}^n$. What I know:

- $f$ is differentiable
- $f$ is strictly (but not strongly) concave
- $f$ is bounded from above

As I see it, this is enough to say that there is a unique maximizer, but it is *not* enough to say that this maximizer is in $\mathbb{R}^n$. What condition should I add such that I can guarantee that this is the case?

As an example, for $n = 1$, consider the function
$$f(x) = ax - e^x, \quad a \ge 0.$$

the function is strictly concave and bounded by above for any $a$, however:

- for $a > 0$, it has a maximizer $x^\star \in \mathbb{R}$
- for $a = 0$, the "maximizer" is $-\infty \not\in \mathbb{R}$.

So I suppose a summary of the question is: **what condition, in addition to differentiability, strict concavity and upper-boundedness, should a function have in order to ensure existence and uniqueness of a maximizer?**

Comment: the usual sufficient condition is bounded (super) level set, or stronger: $f(x)\to -\infty$ for $\|x\|\to \infty$.

Comment: @user251257, isn't the "bounded super level set" necessary as well? Actually that sounds like a very light condition, as it seemingly doesn't even require $f$ to be differentiable.

Comment: Bounded level set is also necessary if $f$ is strict convex. Sometimes it's easy, sometimes it hard to check.

Comment: Sorry, i meant strictly concave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stationary point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is sufficient.

Comment: Ah, excellent. You were mentioning differentiability - actually this is something I can assume too. I will edit my question.

Comment: it is also necessary, as the domain is open.